# How to get unique and consistent device id on Apple device

Tags: ios, security, encryption, analytics

I need to generate a device ID that complies the following criteria:

- It is universally unique.
- It is consistent (as much as possible), i.e. it stays the same for the same device.
- It requires minimal permissions.
- It is legal to be transferred and stored.

The solution, for example, could be a hardware ID which is accessible with no special permissions which is then hashed and sent over the wire, I just don't know if there is any.

---

*P.S. I don't want to store anything in the keychain or anywhere else. Just generate on the fly, and remain the same, independently from the app it's being generated on. And resetting it during factory reset or other rare occasions is fine.*

Comment: and it is not possible

Comment: how does any analytics service work then if they don't have a working device id?

Comment: we can get merchant id but it changes when user reinstall the app, so for this reason we have to store our own generated id in keychain and i think they do the same thing

Comment: What do you have against the keychain option?

Comment: How is it better than IDFA?
Can user edit/delete it? Can multiple apps access it?

Answer (score 0):

While I could access some device specific token in the past, this is not possible any longer.

The API will serve you with a unique identifier for the app installation on that particular device. It seems storing that token and sharing it using the keychain (if not already present from another app) seems to be your best bet at the moment.

This is a necessity to protect users' privacy, and I strongly suggest not to work against that and compromise the concept (and I think it's prohibited in any AppStore app anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how about IDFA?

Comment: IDFA can be disabled by the user in the settings app.